# Angularjs scope array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
      $scope.Getallitem = function() {
          $scope.Store = [];
          $scope.Store[0] = {}
          $scope.Store[1] = {};
          $scope.Store[2] = {};
          $scope.Store[0].StoreName = "Test1";
          $scope.Store[1].StoreName = "Test2";
          $scope.Store[2].StoreName = "Test3";
        }
```

I want to convert this to this.

```
Getallitem();
function Getallitem() {
  $http.get('/Coupons/GetStore').success(function(data) {
    $scope.Store = data;
  });
}
```

That's my data value from database.

> $scope.StoreName = [
>                       'Flipkart',
>                       'Amazon',
>                       'Snapdeal',
>                       'Jabong',
>                       'Trendin',
>                       'Lenskart',
>                       'Zovi',
>                       'BabyOye',
>                       'ShopMore24',
>                       'BasicsLife',
>                       'PrettySecrets',
>                       'American Swan',
>                       'ShopClues',
>                       'FernsNPetals',
>                       'Pepperfry',
>                       'Koovs',
>                       'FoodPanda',
>                       'BookmyFlower',
>                       'Printvenue',
>                       'Amar Chitra Katha',
>                       'Booking',
>                       'TicketGoose',
>                       'Myntra',
>                       'FirstCry',
>                       'Archies Online',
>                       'Dominos',
>                       'Bewakoof',
>                       'Healthkart',
>                       'Zivame',
>                       'eBay',
>                       'Paytm',
>                       'Surat Diamond',
>                       'Groupon',
>                       'indiatimes',
>                       'Yatra Hotels',
>                       'Thomas Cook Hotels',
>                       'FabFurnish',
>                       'VistaPrint',
>                       'KFC',
>                       'Mobikwik',
>                       'JustEat',
>                       'Candere',
>                       'Eureka Forbes',
>                       'Simplilearn',
>                       'Thomas Cook Flights',
>                       'Nord51',
>                       'ClickSense',
>                       'The Mobile Store',
>                       'MakeMyTripHotels',
>                       'Expedia',
>                       'HomeShop18',
>                       'StarCJ',
>                       'Fashionara',
>                       'BigFlix',
>                       'IndiaCircus',
>                       'Yepme',
>                       'Infibeam',
>                       'Purplle',
>                       'AliExpress',
>                       'HappilyUnmarried',
>                       'BagItToday',
>                       'Croma',
>                       'Naaptol',
>                       'ManiacStore',
>                       'D2HShop',
>                       'AskMeBazaar',
>                       'Rediff',
>                       'Xiaomi',
>                       'Syberplace',
>                       'makemytrip',
>                       'nearbuy',
>                       'GreenDust',
>                       'Tatacliq',
>                       'LeMall'];

Comment: So where you have stuck?

Comment: Unclear what you want ?

Comment: sir test 1, test 2 etc is hardcoded , when i use that way list works fine. but the thing is my values are in the second code ie in data

Comment: so i want data to be used instead of test1,test2. There is list of values in data

Answer (score 2):

JS Code like

```
        function newArrayCreation(data) {
            $scope.newArray = [];
            angular.forEach(data, function (v1) {
                var myObj = {StoreName: v1};
                $scope.newArray.push(myObj);
            });
            return $scope.newArray;
        }

        function Getallitem() {
            $http.get('/Coupons/GetStore').success(function (data) {
                $scope.Store = newArrayCreation(data);
            });
        }
        Getallitem();
```

HTML Code to display Store Name

```
<span data-ng-repeat="optionAry in Store">
    <span class="badge" data-ng-bind="optionAry.StoreName"></span>
</span>
```

Output looks like below

[image]

Comment: Sir list comes from database and this values are in data. I dont want any hard coded value.

Comment: yes @KavalPatel , i don't know why people just downvoted immediately .

Comment: @AsadKapadia please check my solution, i think this will helps your problem

Comment: Sir il explain again in detail my question

Comment: @AsadKapadia yes please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091205/8659524  .. This is my code . This works perfectly fine as per requirement. But the data is hard coded if you see as Test1 , Test2 etc.....And i dont want it hardcoded. I have Values Coming from database in data .How should i modify it